# Re: SMS subscription query

Tags: java

I have a dating application that reads from two tables i.e. a Users table and an SMS Subscription table.

The users table has all the personal details about the subscribers, i.e. Their Gender, Names, Religion, Profession, etc.

While the Subscription Table has the Frequency of times a subscriber should receive Automated texts from the system. The texts received are basically contact details of the opposite sex.

My question is this, how can i generate a query that sends random contact details of the opposite sex at any given time.

The Code below only executes queries for user initiated requests only. While am more interested in also incorporating a query of sending random texts of the opposite sex to my users, especially whenever the users fail to submit their requests themselves. How should I go about it, Kind Regards!

```
public void ExecuteSubscriptions() {
/* 609 */     this.var_returnMessage = "";
/* 610 */     String text = "";
/* 611 */     SqlConn lConn = null;
/*     */     try
/*     */     {
/* 615 */       String queryTmp = "select abs(DATEDIFF(datelastsent, NOW())) as gapTime, phone, request, SubscriptionFrequency from  where abs(DATEDIFF(datelastsent, NOW())) > 0 ";
/* 616 */       lConn = new SqlConn(false, true);
/* 617 */       if ((lConn.sqlConnection != null) && (lConn.statement != null))
/*     */       {
/* 619 */         ResultSet rs = lConn.statement.executeQuery(queryTmp);
/*     */ 
/* 621 */         if (rs != null)
/*     */         {
/* 623 */           String value = "";
/*     */ 
/* 625 */           while (rs.next()) {
/* 626 */             value = rs.getString("SubscriptionFrequency").toUpperCase().substring(0, 2);
/* 627 */             String[] smsParts;
/*     */             smsParts = rs.getString("request").split("");
/* 628 */             this.var_sender = rs.getString("phone");
/* 629 */             int var_num = Integer.parseInt(value);
/* 630 */             if (Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("gapTime")) >= var_num) {
/* 631 */               if ((!GetResults(CreateRequestQuery(smsParts, RequestTypes.NEWRESULTSONLY))) && 
/* 632 */                 (!GetResults(CreateRequestQuery(smsParts, RequestTypes.MIXEDRESULTS)))) {
/* 633 */                 this.var_totalResultsForUser = 0;
/* 634 */                 this.var_returnMessage = "Dear Subscriber, at the moment there were no results matching your subscription criteria, try again later.";
/*     */               }
/*     */ 
/* 637 */               text = new StringBuilder().append("update subscriptions set datelastsent = NOW() where phone = '").append(rs.getString("phone")).append("' and request = '").append(rs.getString("request")).append("'").toString();
/*     */             }
/*     */ 
/*     */           }
/*     */ 
/*     */         }
/*     */ 
/* 645 */         if ((this.var_returnMessage != null) && 
/* 646 */           (EngineIgniter.SendMessage(this.var_sender, "KQ Solutions", this.var_returnMessage))) {
/* 647 */           this.var_dm.CreateEntity(text);
/*     */         }
/*     */       }
/*     */     }
/*     */     catch (Exception ex)
/*     */     {
/* 653 */       this.var_dm.LogError(ex.getMessage(), "GENERIC");
/*     */     }
/*     */   }
/*     */
```

Comment: why do you have line numbers generated ? Surely your editor could just show the line number ?

Comment: My apologies about the line numbers... Forgot to remove them.. My Bad

Comment: This code snippet is from a decompiler, isnt it ?

Comment: Those line numbers in the source code look intimidating.

Comment: Yes true, had to decompile an old app after my laptop died on me.. And am trying to make add modifications to the application. Thanks

Comment: Hope not too intimidating to make a aide in generation of the noted queries, Thanks!

Comment: @ObieMD5 Never underestimate the desires of some people.

Comment: @ObieMD5  The system is much more smarter...It is actually not how it works, the random details are a safety net to help those who haven't chosen to be sent details that match their search criteria, not to feel left out.. Till they learn how to request details that match their needs.. Thanks

Comment: You can use the SQL `rand()` function

Comment: @TimHerold Will look into it.. but how do you suggest I should execute that query... Given that when a (male) user wants to receive female details of the following criteria Age (25-35), Christian, etc.. They send the following request... : Fwd 25 35 christian, Thanks!

Comment: @KnightSlayer take a look at the first [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18274512/2362664)

Comment: @TimHerold, Am currently looking into it, Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

"randomly" probably isnt the best way. You will want to maybe randomly select a portion of users who have not had a generated text message in x amount of time.

For example select a random user who has not had a text in 6 hours.

You havent said which RDBMS you are using but the query would look similar to

```
SELECT * from subscriptions where sex = (sex variable) and datelastsent < date_add (now(), interval - 6 hours) order by rand() limit 1
```